# Set UIButton tittle to specific position for all screen sizes

Tags: swift, uibutton, autolayout

Below I have a button.

[image]

It is actually a UIButton with an Image inside. The problem is that the "Scan Product" is inside the image too, isn't a title.

First of all I want to know if apple allows this, cause I can't find something in the guidelines.

Also is there a way to place the title lets say at 25% of the buttons height.

**EDIT**

```
scanTest.setTitle("Test", for: .normal)
        let x = scanTest.frame.origin.x * 0.35
        scanTest.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: x, right: 0)
```

This is to place the title at 25% of the buttons height. But on iPhone SE looks wrong.

[image]

I mean I don't think that this is the 25%.

Comment: parameter multiplier in its constraints

Comment: 1) Yes it is allowed
2) As far as I can understand you can use multiplier on constraints, 25% = 0.25 hieght of image, maybe I didn't understant your question. If you elaborate a little it will be helpful

Comment: Yes you understood  correctly. I tried using multiplier, but on different iPhones it looks different .Look at my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using AutoLayout for everything, so you can add an invisible `UIView` on top of your image that has 25% of the image's height and then just add the button to that view and make sure that the `topAnchor` of the button is the same as the new `UIView`.

Let me know if you couldn't understand so I can make you an example.

UPDATE:

You can try to run this, it may not be the optimal solution but it will do the job. (you can play with background colors to understand the architecture)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    view.backgroundColor = .white

    let imageView = UIImageView()
    view.addSubview(imageView)
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

    let holder = UIView()
    view.addSubview(holder)
    holder.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    holder.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.25).isActive = true
    holder.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    holder.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    holder.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

    let label = UILabel()
    holder.addSubview(label)
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: holder.topAnchor).isActive = true
    label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    label.text = "Hello"
    label.textAlignment = .center

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I use autoLayout for everything. it works perfect. The problem is with the title. Do you suggest to put helper view with a label for a title?

Comment: @NickStefanidis I just added an example. I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Answer of first question :- Apple will definitely allow this.

Answer of Second question : - Because title is inside image ,title cannot change from xcode but you can edit image.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I take out the title from the image can I place a title in Xcode in the same position for all screen sizes? I don't know if I explain this right.

Comment: Yes you can dot this with AutoLayout

Answer (score 0):

you can set the title and image according to title and image insets via 'size inspector'. 
One more way you can take one view and inside that take UIImage(your image) and UILabel(put your title) and above both UIButton for more customisation.